# Option monad in scala

Tags: scala, monads, scala-option

how is meant to work Option monad? I'm browsing the [scala api](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) and there is an example (I mean the second one),

> Because of how for comprehension works, if None is returned from request.getParameter, the entire expression results in None

But when I try this code:

```
 val upper = for {
   name <- None //request.getParameter("name")
   trimmed <- Some(name.trim)
   upper <- Some(trimmed.toUpperCase) if trimmed.length != 0
 } yield upper
 println(upper.getOrElse(""))
```

I get a compile error. How is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You get a compiler error because of this

```
  name <- None
```

That way, the type of `None` is set to `None.type` and the variable `name` is inferred to be of type `Nothing`. (That is, it would have this type if it actually existed but obviously the for comprehension does not even get to creating it at runtime.) Therefore no method `name.trim` exists and it won’t compile.

If you had `request.getParameter("name")` available, its type would be `Option[String]`, `name` would potentially have type `String` and `name.trim` would compile.

You can work around this by specifying the type of `None`:

```
  name <- None: Option[String]
```

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Kevin's answer, you can avoid wrapping values in `Some()` by using the `=` operator instead of the `<-` operator:

```
val upper = for {
   name <- None: Option[String] //request.getParameter("name")
   trimmed = name.trim
   upper = trimmed.toUpperCase if trimmed nonEmpty
} yield upper
```

The for-comprehension will compile to something very similar to Kevin's version, but I often find it more clear to use `map` and `filter` explicitly to avoid clutter (e.g. extra variable names) that add nothing to the semantic content of the expression.

Comment: Wow, I like it...  Wasn't even aware that this syntax was possible!

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Debilski's answer, you also don't need to explicitly wrap subsequent values in `Some()`, the only value you're actually mapping over is the original `name`.

A better approach would be be to use the `map` and `filter` operations directly instead of a for-comprehension:

*NOTE: behind the scenes, the Scala compiler will convert a for-comprehension to a combination of map/flatMap/filter anyway, so this approach will never be less efficient than a for-comprehension, and may well be more efficient*

```
def clean(x:Option[String]) = x map { _.trim.toUpperCase } filterNot { _.isEmpty }

val param = None : Option[String] // request.getParameter("name")
println( clean(param).getOrElse("") )
```

Comment: @oxbow_lakes no argument there!  *Anything* has got to be better than `length != 0` :)